# Change the name of a cloned VM without losing the source VM

Tags: active-directory

I have an ESXi host on a domain, and I am having some issues with cloning VMs that the IT consultants don't seem to be able to help with.
I am able to clone a VHD, make a new VM with that VHD, flag it as copied not moved (to get a new MAC address) and launch the resultant VM. But according to the IT folks I can't then change the computer name of that VM, without causing problems with the first VM. According to the consultants the ONLY way to get a new VM is to pay them to manually create a new VM, inlcuding the Windows install, which they do from a 5 year old ISO that requires a manual update of Windows version, plus all windows updates, plus joining the domain. They can't be bothered to automate ANYTHING. Of course not, they get paid not to.
But I am certain that both Cloning and Templates are viable VMware paths to new VMs on the domain. I just don't know the ins and outs of DNS/DHCP as it applies to a Windows Domain, and IT are not being helpful. Can anyone verify that I am not daft, and Cloning IS a viable route? And perhaps explain the process either I need to go through to rename the cloned VM myself (ideally) or the path that I need IT to go through to do the same (less ideal because getting them to do anything is like pulling teach)?
One thought I had was to log on to the VM, take it off the domain, change the name, then rejoin the domain, as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/340196/how-can-i-rejoin-a-windows-machine-to-the-domain-without-losing-user-data-if-tru). Am I understanding that right, and this is viable? Will I have any issues then logging in from the original VM that still has the old name? I am hoping the issue is just with having two machines with the same name logged in at once, not with ever having two machines with the same name log in.
I should mention that I should be able to do that because I have, get this, DOMAIN ADMIN rights. As an external consultant for Autodesk installs IT gave me DOMAIN ADMIN rights. After I told them the ONLY thing I need is local admin rights when actually doing the installs, and the better approach would be to give me personally standard user rights and then have a dedicated user account with Local Admin only. But no, I have DA, and four other people in house, who actively do the Autodesk installs I am helping to automate have DA rights. ON THEIR REGULAR USER ACCOUNTS. The idiots are clueless, but it's what I have to work with and at least in this case those rights are useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are right in a certain way, that is you can't directly use this cloned VM on a domain network without first dealing with the issue that after cloning you have two computers with the same name and domain account on the network.

But you can work around it. First, disconnect a clone from the network while it is powered off. Boot the system, login using *local* admin account, disjoin the machine from your domain. Change it's IP address and rename the computer. Alternatively, you can `sysprep` your clone to get things right.
Then, boot with the network connected and join the domain as usual.

Comment: Ah, looks like I was close. How do I "disconnect a clone from the network while it is powered off. "? As for SysPrep, I had no idea I could run that on an existing install disconnected from the domain. Seems I need to figure out how to do that.

Comment: You use esxi, so just uncheck `connected` and `connect at power on` checkboxes next to your network adapter in virtual machine properties. As for `sysprep`, running `sysprep /generalize /oobe /mode:vm` should suffice in your case

Comment: So it looks like I have a couple of steps here. 1: create a local account on the machine that is an Administrator 2: Stop the VM and do the disconnect as described 3: Clone the VM (to a new host in this case) 4: Create new VM, also disconnected 5: Start VM, logon as local admin and disjoin from domain 6: Rename computer, reboot and shut down 7 Reenable network and reboot 8: Logon as local admin, Rejoin domain

Comment: Do I have that right? :)

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Woot! I hope to also have the clone sorted, and I can try it. Followup question, does the ESXi Template process automate any of this? I assume creating a new VM from a template means you have a new VM you can immediately use. Or do you need to do this procedure on the resultant VM before it's safe to use?

Comment: If using templates, you should `sysprep` your VM, shutdown it and only then convert it to template. Then this template could be used multiple times.

Comment: AHA! Totally makes sense to do the prep first. Monday morning, just had coffee brain.

Comment: Well, it seems there is one other nuance. I have to union the domain on the original VM before anything else, because that needs to be done WHILE I am connected to the domain, which makes sense.

Comment: And I can't clone with a snapshot, so if/when I screw something up, I REALLY screw up, because getting IT to rebuild a VM is a PITA.

Comment: You need to join a domain when your cloned system has a different name, so if we're talking about templates then the VM inside template should not be a domain member.

Comment: I'm talking about even earlier than that. I need to clone a VHD that has already left the domain. But I worry about getting THAT VM back ON the domain. So I have made a backup clone of the HD on the domain, then I will log in to the machine as DA, leave the domain, log off & disconnect from the network, log in again as the local admin, change the machine name, and clone again for distribution. Then I will  join the domain again with the original VM and unchanged name, buy deleting that now modified VHD and cloning the backup back to the original location and name. I hope it all works. :)

Comment: You don't have to do that. You clone a VM that is a domain member. Then on the clone you disconnect the network, login as local admin account, leave the domain (it would allow you to do so in disconnected state), rename the computer or do a sysprep, then reboot the clone, connect it to the network and join a domain again.

Comment: I can see I am going to end up trying a number of things and learning a lot, while spending WAY too much time. :) I think what I got wrong was trying to leave the domain while logged in as DA. Next I'll try as you say, but I will have the backup, so I can clone the already workgroup VM and still restore (or try to restore) if need be. We have no backup on either host, and never will, so having some mechanism to backup VMs to an external USB HD seems appropriate.

Comment: Well, I thought I had the same problem again, but I forgot that my previous attempt to just rename while joined to the domain resulted in the old name being corrupted some how, as well as the new name being unavailable. So IT "fixed" the VM by just creating a new computer name, rather than actually fixing it. And I had forgotten that and was using the old computer name to try to log in locally. Got as far as leaving the domain, but now, just like previous attempt, my Domain Admin account has been locked, so I can't use it to rejoin the domain. I really hate these IT clowns.

Comment: After leaving the domain your domain account would not work on the machine. You have to login using local admin account, select join domain and then, when prompted, enter your domain admin account credentials.

Comment: Exactly, and at that point, logged in as local admin, joining domain with domain credentials, I was getting an error saying account locked. Which I got yesterday too, and it really was locked, because I couldn't use it for any logons, VM or physical machine. But in this case it's because I forgot to include the domain prefix, and Microsoft threw an unhelpful error, and by coincidence I had seen that error just yesterday, and I blew a gasket. This whole exercise has been daft, but once it's done I'll be able to look back and see all the things I have learned.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at vmware converter, that is able to do the job, but it requires vcenter. You can rename a windows device, but if it's a domain controller then it requires a more extended procedure.

With PowerShell it's one line:

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "Server044" -DomainCredential Domain01\Admin01 -Restart
```

Comment: Unfortunately vCenter is not an option here. I have to do it with a minimal ESXi install or not at all.

Comment: Checkout the StarWind V2V converter, it's free. But a domain controller needs extra carefulness. Search Google for cloning domain controller vm, or hire me hahahaha lol. I will make an extra post what you need to do before spinning up the cloned VM

Comment: VMware converter does not need vcenter, it's a standalone product. But it hasn't been updated in years, it may work with a modern ESXi, or it may not.